# How do i run an AWS lambda function on a schedule depending on the output of my code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

So the purpose of my lambda function is to check if a success file is in a certain s3 bucket path. If it's not there then it should send a failure message to slack. If it is there then it should trigger a dag to run manually. So at the moment I've got the code working for that but I want to retry the function IF there is no success file for the next 10 hours every 15 minutes. If after all those attempts, it's still not there then I want to send the failure notification to slack. At the moment, my event bridge cron expression schedule run of the lambda is spamming the slack failure message x amount of times or triggering the dag x amount of times. I want to exit the schedule if there is a success file there and trigger the dag once but i want it to run again if its no there and then send a failure message on the last retry that ive got scheduled. Is this possible? My code is below and my eventbridge cron is for mon-friday, every 15 minutes from 4 am to 1pm. Any guidance on a possible solution would be appreciated!

````
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #slack and airflow config 
    slack_webhook_url_details = ""
    dag_id = 'sample_dag'
    airflow_url=''
    
    def send_slack_message(slack_webhook_url,slack_message):
        slack_payload = {'text':slack_message}
        response = requests.post(slack_webhook_url, json.dumps(slack_payload))
        response_json = response.text 
        print('response after posting to slack: '+ str(response_json))

    def initialize_paths():
        global bucket
        global path
        global dt
        
        two_days_ago = date.today() - timedelta(days=2)
        dt = two_days_ago.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        #add for loop logic for iterating through countries in bucket
        bucket = ""
        path = f"test_lambda/US/{dt}/_SUCCESS"

    def check_file_exists():
        print(bucket,path)
        s3 = resource('s3')
        try:
            #check if file exists
            s3.Object(bucket, path).load()
            logging.info(f'_SUCCESS file exists with at path: {bucket}/{path} for the following date: {dt}')
            #trigger dag run
            mwaa_env_name = 'airflow-prod-env'
            dag_name= 'sample_dag'
            mwaa_cli_command = 'dags trigger'
            client = boto3.client('mwaa')
            mwaa_cli_token = client.create_cli_token(Name=mwaa_env_name)
            conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(mwaa_cli_token['WebServerHostname'])
            payload = mwaa_cli_command + " " + dag_name
            headers = {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + mwaa_cli_token['CliToken'],
              'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            }
            conn.request("POST", "/aws_mwaa/cli", payload, headers)
            res = conn.getresponse()
            data = res.read()
            dict_str = data.decode("UTF-8")
            mydata = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
            return base64.b64decode(mydata['stdout'])
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as errorStdOut:
            if errorStdOut.response['Error']['Code'] >= "401":
                error_message= f'_SUCCESS file NOT detected at path: {bucket}/{path} for the following date: {dt}'
                logging.info(error_message)
                send_slack_message(slack_webhook_url_details,error_message)
            else:
               logging.info('Error, something went wrong connecting to lambda')
    initialize_paths()
    check_file_exists()```
````

Comment: DynamoDB is a very lightweight way to store e.g. the failure counter or the "first miss" time or something like that. On each lambda invocation you can then compare and update that counter and only alert when a threshold is met.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, I'll look into that for handling the slack failure messages. What about successful runs that trigger the dag. On most days, it will work on the first run, is it possible to switch off the lambda for that day so that it only triggers the dag once.

Comment: Multiple options, you could make the lambda actually disable the rule triggering and have another rule daily that triggers yet another lambda which enables the first rule on each day. Alternatively just set a flag in dynamo that "today" the run was already successful (obviously add a date for what "today" that the case) and first the lamda does is check if dynamo already tells you the lambda already run successfully and if it did just end the execution of the lambda. That should only take a few ms of runtime and will not even cost a dollar / year.